# Excel - nested formula to return string if meets a condition

Tags: excel-formula

This is beyond a vlookup since it needs to meet a condition before returning a value... but I don't know what it should be.

I have a table (Table 1) that includes unique ID's.  I have another table (table 2) that includes IDs, name of course, and order in which the course was taken (value = 1, 2, 3). An ID can appear multiple times within (Table 2) .  I need a formula for Table 1 that will look at the ID in table 2, and if the course order = 1 (in other words, this is the first course the took), then return the name of the course. In the following columns I would do the same for courses 2, 3, 4, etc...  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQqCG.png)

So for Table 1, I'd like to see "Science" populated in First Class for ID 123, Math for 2nd Class, and so on.

Comment: You will need to use an INDEX/MATCH formula Using the SMALL or AGGREGATE formula.  Without data mock up it is hard to get more specific than that

Comment: Thanks Scott - I'm attached a screen shot to the explanation above.  Hope you're able to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$10:$C$14,MATCH($A3&"|"&COLUMN(A:A),$A$10:$A$14&"|"&$B$10:$B$14,0)),"")
```

Being an ***Array Formula*** it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter whenever exiting edit mode on the cell that has the formula.

[image]

Comment: Thanks again Scott.  Table 1 is actually in Sheet 1 and Table 2 in Sheet 2 so how do I address &column(A:A) above?  I'm trying to figure out from the formula you provided how it knows to pull science into the first column and math into the second.  What do the pipes signify?

Comment: @KDS Column(A:A) is just a counter, it returns 1 then when dragged to the next column it changes to column(B:B) and returns 2.  It can be on either sheet it does not matter, so I would leave it referring to the sheet on which the formula is found to avoid extra typing.